# ruby on rails beginner problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a easy php installed on my windows 7. and also mysql.
I installed ruby and ruby mine, started with this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

After creating DB and reroute the root url, when try to navigate to 127.0.0.1:3000
the site just get stuck, the request take forever.

any tips?

Comment: Did you start the Rails server? Try `rails s` from the command line (or, in Windows `ruby rails s`).

Comment: Hmm is there anything in the log.  It is in the log directory, probably named development.log

Comment: is this ok? => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-02-26 17:51:36] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-02-26 17:51:36] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
[2011-02-26 17:51:36] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5352 port=3000

Comment: the log says 
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Feb 26 17:49:31 +0200 2011

Comment: If you press Ctrl+R in your browser, does the log say that again, or just once?

Comment: if I refresh chrome returns to the home page so no log message is added

Comment: Please post your routes.rb and the code for the action you're trying to execute.

Comment: I managed the problem by my own, It works now, I guess its something with apache that host the mysql and ruby that hosted on other thing that messed thing up, so with sqlite its ok, thanks anyway

Comment: Beside your specific problem, I suggest you to set up your environment in Ubuntu, even better inside a virtual machine, I tried both win and linux and I would never go back.

Comment: yea, you are not the first who tells me to run it with linux. just wanna start in windows, and then deep dive with linux.

Comment: So can someone answer, that windows sucks with ruby and I'll accept?

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with mysql connection, not related to mysql.